# jQuery Global variable use

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
var products = [];

$(document).ready(function($){  

    $.fn.load_products = function(){      
        $.getJSON('/restaurant/get_products',function(data){
            products = data[0];
            alert(products[0]['idProduct']);//this works fine           
        });
        // EDITED: alert was here, but was a mistake sorry
    }

    $.fn.draw_products = function(){
        alert(products[0]['idProduct']); //this doesn't work            
    }

    $(this).load_products();      
    $(this).draw_products();
}
```

I have products declared in the global scope but it looks like it's redefined inside load_products again.

When I execute this it says products[0] is undefined.

EDIT: some extra info. The error in console appears after the alert execution.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and say your products array is empty.

Comment: try logging the whole product variable to console, it may that your product array is empty and you are trying to access element out if it.

Comment: looks like async loading problem

Comment: `load_products` sends a ajax request, while the script execution continues with call to `draw_products()`, but the problem is how the alert in `load_products()` works, even that should not work

Comment: Strange, when the line saying "this works fine" runs, the call to $.getJSON has not finished yet, so products cannot have been populated. Cant be any products in the array at that moment! If data contains an array of products, it would also make sense to use products = data; instead of products = data[0];

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake, I copied the alert outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `draw_products` gets called before the AJAX call in `load_products` returns.  You will need to call `draw_products` in a callback inside the AJAX call.

Comment: could I make the ajax call synchronous with this? (I know this is contra natura AJAX = Asynchronous Javascript XML)

Comment: @beerLantern don't make ajax call synchronous